# InArgument IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, android-activity

How to transfer IEnumerable value into InArgument in CodeActivity in Workflow

```
public sealed class CreateInterview : CodeActivity<int>
    {        
public InArgument<List<InterviewerList>> InterviewerLists { get; set; }

protected override int Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
var interviewerLists = context.GetValue(this.InterviewerLists); // interviewerLists = null
}
```

Hot to set and get IEnumerable Value

Comment: please help me. How i can pass param type of IEnumerable in Activity to Workflow

Comment: Try to be more specific, where you want to pass the parameter? Some sort of ActivityDesigner? Property box? Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up searching this exact same thing thinking a problem I had with my workflow was due to it not supporting `IEnumerable` (which is false).

[Here is a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/workflowteam/archive/2012/07/27/how-to-use-linq-in-a-workflow.aspx) detailing the usage of `IEnumerable` and Linq in Workflow Foundation. Basically, it works exactly like any other `InArgument` instance, and the value can be obtained the same way using the `Get` method.

Of course, to provide the value in the first place, you have to pass in an expression in the XAML file or designer to the activity which returns the `IEnumerable`.